# How to create a Custom Editor script that shows non-native classes in the inspector in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a class that is not extending a native class and therefore variables of that type don't show up in the inspector.

If I were to extend said class by a native one, variables of that type would show in the inspector, but I wouldn't actually be able to set them to anything, because they are contained within a ScriptableObject and apparently those two types don't fit together.

I tried writing a CustomPropertyDrawer, but it still doesn't show the variable. This is my code (in C#):

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(AScriptableObjectClassThatShouldDisplayTheVariableInItsInspector))]
public class ShowVariable : PropertyDrawer
{

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        base.OnGUI(position, property, label);

        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        Rect rect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, 50, position.height);

        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property.FindPropertyRelative("nameOfVariable"));

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

}
```

This is the class that contains a variable of the class that should be displayed:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Syntax : ScriptableObject
{
  public GameLevelFunction nameOfVariable;
}
```

And this is basically how my class that should be displayed in the inspector looks like:

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class GameLevelFunction
{
  //literally two methods
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without `abstract` in `GameLevelFunction`?

Comment: @frankhermes Just did and the name of the variable shows up, but there's no field for me to put anything in.

Comment: That said, it's actually not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have a class that is not extended by a Unity-native class. An instance of that class exists in every scriptable object of a certain type. I want to to be able to set those instances via the inspector like I would with a float for example. BUT, since the class doesn't extend a native Unity class it doesn't show up in the inspector. If I were to change that, a field would show up, but I couldn't place anything in it. How do I solve this?